# React Hook "useTranslation" is called in function "getMyMenu" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am invoking the `useTranslation` hook from within a normal function as below

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";


function getMyMenu(a) {
  const { t } = useTranslation('translations');
  
  if (a.showRoute) {
      a.label = t(a.label);
    return a;
  }
}



export const MyNav = props => {
  let tabs = recurseFn(getMyMenu, props.routes);
}
```

I get the following error. Is there no way to fix this? For some strange reason, I was able to see the similar code pattern working in other project. Any additional config needed to make this work?

Updated:

This is how my `recurseFn` looks like:

```
export const recurseFn = (chk, [head, ...tail]) => {
  if (head === undefined) return [];
  if (chk(head)) {
    return [head, ...recurseFn(chk, tail)];
  }

  return [...recurseFn(chk, tail)];
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix it by moving the `useTranslation` hook to the `MyNav` component body and pass the translation function `t` as a closure in `getMyMenu`.

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const MyNav = props => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('translations');

  function getMyMenu(a) {
    if (a.showRoute) {
      a.label = t(a.label);
      return a;
    }
  }

  let tabs = recurseFn(getMyMenu, props.routes);

  ...
}
```

## Edit

> I just updated with how my `recurseFn` looks like. Is it possible to
> pass "t" to it?

### Solution 1 - Pass `t` explicitly to all functions

You could certainly update the function signature of `recurseFn` to also consume a "t" (translation?) function, but you'd still need to then also pass `t` into `chk` which would necessitate updating the original `getMyMenu` function to consume an additional argument.

Example:

```
function getMyMenu(t, a) { // <-- consume additional t argument
  if (a.showRoute) {
      a.label = t(a.label);
    return a;
  }
}

...

export const recurseFn = (chk, [head, ...tail], t) => { // <-- consume additional t argument
  if (head === undefined) return [];
  if (chk(t, head)) { // <-- pass t to chk
    return [head, ...recurseFn(chk, tail, t)]; // <-- pass t on recursion
  }

  return [...recurseFn(chk, tail, t)]; // <-- pass t on recursion
};

...

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const MyNav = props => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('translations');

  let tabs = recurseFn(getMyMenu, props.routes, t); // <-- pass t on recursion

  ...
}
```

### Solution 2 - A better solution using a curried callback

In this case I think making `getMyMenu` a curried function can help you enclose `t` in the callback and allow it to be declared externally to any React component. The `recurseFn` function doesn't need to know anything about `t`, so why expose it there, right?

```
const getMyMenu = t => a => {
  if (a.showRoute) {
    a.label = t(a.label);
    return a;
  }
}
```

Now you destructure `t` from the `useTranslation` hook return value and pass to the curried `getMyMenu` function. This is a similar idea to closing over the `t` function in the callback like we did above in the first answer.

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const MyNav = props => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('translations');

  let tabs = recurseFn(getMyMenu(t), props.routes);

  ...
}
```

Now from `recurseFn`'s perspective, `t` is enclosed in the `chk` callback and `recurseFn` didn't need to explicitly handle receiving and passing `t` around.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I just updated with how my recurseFn looks like. Is it possible to pass "t" to it ?

Comment: @testndtv Sure, I've updated my answer with what I believe you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks again...yes, so I am inclined to solution 2...However, seeing an error on the line const getMyMenu => t => a => {...}
The error says "Const declarations require an initialization value"

Comment: @testndtv Oops, quite right, one too many `=>`, I've updated answer. It should be `const getMyMenu = t => a => {.....`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot...this seems to be working perfectly now....though last question...So taking a step back, while it seems like we should call hook from within a React function component nor a custom React Hook function, are there some exceptions....coz I did see this same code in another application and it probably seemed to work fine...So any exceptions to the rule ?

Comment: @testndtv Exceptions? No, not really. The [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) are pretty clear about where hooks can be called. They can only be called from the top-level of functional components and other react hooks. I'm guessing the code you saw was either misunderstood (*by you or the author*), or was actually incorrect and they didn't have updated React hook linting rules checking for invalid usage, which it would/should have flagged.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this same issue by ensuring that the function name was capitalized. The complaint explicitly stated that "React component names must start with a an uppercase letter." After correcting this issue the ESLint message vanished.